# When does the Dragon Ball Super Broly movies occur in the series

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Which episodes of *Dragon Ball Super* does the *Dragon Ball Super Broly* movie come in between? So if I was to watch *Dragon Ball Super* to make sense of the story in the movie which episodes should I have watched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Dragon Ball Super Broly movie* is set after the *Dragon Ball Super series*. The movie is made in a way where you don't really need to have any prior knowledge of Dragon Ball Super or even Dragon Ball in general(Although, having knowledge with regard to the same would definitely help).

With regard to your main question, if you were to watch the Dragon Ball Super series before, it doesn't really make a significant difference with regard to plot. It would mainly help you realize the level of strength of the characters and the antagonist and maybe a few small details.

However, in conclusion, you don't necessarily have to watch the series to understand the movie.