# Timeline of Dragonball Super Broly Movie

Tags: dragon-ball-super

According to [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/50700/when-does-the-dragon-ball-super-broly-movies-occur-in-the-series) query's answer, `The Dragon Ball Super Broly movie is set after the Dragon Ball Super series`. My query is, if its timeline is set after the Dragon Ball Super series, then why didn't Goku's `U.I.` triggered (Assuming it's spontaneous, and Goku still don't know how to trigger it whenever he wants) when he was pushed to the limit while fighting Broly, and instead he did the fusion with Vegeta?